# During the installation of Kali Linux when I set username and password, this user is root user or non-root user?

Tags: sudo, kali-linux, root, non-root-user

During the installation of Kali Linux when I set username and password, this user is root user or non-root user? If I login into m Linux system using this username and password and type `whoami`, it shows my username. If I type `sudo su -` and enter the password (which I was set during installation) and if then then I run `whoami` it shows current user is root user. In first case it was a non-root user, in second case it was a root user, why ?

Comment: `sudo su -` is better replaced with `sudo -i`

Comment: If you're not familiar with UNIX/Linux systems, I strongly suggest you don't start with Kali. It does things differently because it's a specialised distribution. Start with Mint, Ubuntu, or possibly Fedora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the installation the created user is a non-root privileged user.

[All about sudo](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/sudo/)

> With 2020.1 Kali has swapped to a privileged non-root user by default.

> Because Kali creates a user with administrative privileges by default, users can use sudo right away and supply their password for authentication

Comment: After login with the username and password (created during the installation) I can perform root task by add `sudo` beginning of the command. Now if I create another non-root user, then can I perform root task with this new created user by insert `sudo` before command??

Comment: @SanniddhaChakrabarti No, You need to add it to group `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

The first `whoami` command runs as your standard user account. The second one runs as the `root` administrator account.